# Google Sheets referencing a cell adjacent to a cell on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a calendar in google sheets with each cell referencing a cell value pulled from weekly sheets. I'd like to be able to enter the cell reference for the first of the month, then have the rest of the dates autofill incrementally from that date. For example, first of the month would be referenced like 
`=('4/01/19'!A12)`, then the adjacent cell would point to '4/01/19'!B12, where values for the 2nd of the month have been entered. Since the sheet names will naturally vary week to week and month to month, I'm basically trying to do something like

a1 = `'sheet1'!a1`
b1 = `offset(the-cell-being-referenced-in-a1,0,1)`

Is this possible?

Link to an example of the document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aHLX8LcVpefi9mxHVeU_H6jB97RDhb4_eKD2h39FDzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Added a link to an example document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- paste in **A2** cell:

  ```
  ={INDIRECT(TEXT(A1, "m/d/yy")&"!A12:G12")}
  ```

  [image: 0]
- then select **A2** cell press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**
- select **A8** cell and press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** and continue on **A14**, **A20** etc.

Comment: That did it! That honestly did it better than I'd even hoped for. Thank you!